# Handlebars not showing values

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

My handlebars view is not showing values, instead, it's showing "0" for every handlebars variable. What do I have wrong?

**My handlebars js**

`function reDrawList (){
    var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {name: "Example" , price: "example2"};
    var html    = template(context);
    $( ".scrollable" ).prepend(template);
};`

**My handlebars view**

`<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li class="listnone border_bottom_grey semi_padding thin">
        <div class="circle"><i class="icon-pin"></i></div>
            <span class="grey bold inline quarter_padding_left">
            {{name}}</span>
            <span class="small right white tag_price">{{price}}</span></br>
            <span class="quarter_padding_top inline lightgrey small">
            <i class="icon-location-2 indent20 small"> </i> {{location}}</span>
    </li>
</script>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

html variable didn't have much sense.

Instead, y put the data from (context) directly in template after the prepend method.

`function reDrawList (){
    var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {price: "20€", name: "Example"};
    $( ".scrollable" ).prepend(template(context));
};`

Comment: Indeed, this was the issue, you figured it out few seconds before I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should prepend your compiled html output (`var html = template(context)`) and not your template to your `.scrollable` element.
I've made a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2b5M/336/) to help you.

Code:

```
function reDrawList (){
    var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {name: "example" , price: "$20"};
    var html    = template(context);

    $( ".scrollable" ).prepend(html); // LINE TO PAY ATTENTION TO
};
```

Comment: I fixed it by doing the answer before, is it correct? I think it's the same as yours but with 1 var less

Comment: Sure it's correct, you've just answered your own question!